# Extending my array

Tags: c++

From what I am reading from the book and from prior examples that I have been doing from the book this is what I have come up with.  I appreciate the extra advice but I am trying to learn what the chapter is trying to show me so I can move on and learn the basics before I try code I have never seen before. I want the user to type 0 to end the loop but for some reason the loop keeps going?  I think I may be missing something that is preventing it from stopping.

```
// Ex4_08.cpp
// Initializing pointers with strings
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    bool keepgoing = true;
    int answer;
    while (keepgoing = true)
    {

        const char* pstr[]{ "Aa",                                       // Initializing a pointer array
            "Bb",
            "Cc",
            "Dd",
            "Ee",
            "Ff",
            "Gg",
            "Hh",
            "Ii",
            "Jj",
            "Kk",
            "Ll",
            "Mm",
            "Oo",
            "Pp",
            "Qq",
            "Rr",
            "Ss",
            "Tt",
            "Uu",
            "Vv",
            "Ww",
            "Ss",
            "Yy",
            "Zz",

        };
        const char* pstart{ "Your letter is " };

        int dice{};

        cout << endl
            << "Enter a number between 1 and 26 " << _countof(pstr) << ": ";
        cin >> dice;

        cout << endl;
        if (dice >= 1 && dice <= _countof(pstr))                            // Check input validity
            cout << pstart << pstr[dice - 1];                               // Output star name

        else
            cout << "Sorry, you haven't selected a correct number.";        // Invalid input


        cout << "Do you want to do this again? Type 0 for no: " << endl;
        cin >> answer;
        if (answer == 0)
        {
            keepgoing = false;
        }

    }


    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: could you make it clear what the problem is? can't you add `Gg, Hh` etc.?

Comment: What about using a for loop like `for(char c = 'a' ; c <= 'z'; ++c)` and creating the pairs in the strings using `std::toupper()`?

Comment: I can add more letters, but when I run the program and type anything after 6 it breaks.  I am trying to use an array that will be able to handle all 26 letters with out breaking.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new and I did not realize I could just add more to the array.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Based on the comments at the top of the file, I was able to Google and figure out that you're trying to modify the example from Ivor Horton's book "Beginning Visual C++ 2013."  Please mention this next time for context; you probably got downvoted because people thought you were posting a homework problem, but folks are more sympathetic if you let them know you're doing this on your own.

Comment: Is there a way I can add a loop to this?  I want the user to be able to keep inputting numbers until they want to stop?

Comment: you can use a `while(true)` around and then use the `break` statement if the user input 0 (i.e. `if (dice ==0) break;`

Comment: O I apologize, Yes I am learning coding on my own time.  I want to get a job in programming and work full time.  I am using books to learn.  I apologize.  I will say that next time.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified you initial code sample, using vector and string which are more C++ and easier to use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> // for string
#include <vector>  // for vector
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> pstr;

    for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)  // cycle over the 26 ASCII letters
    {
        std::string temp;     // 
        temp += c - 32;       //  add capital character (e.g A)
        temp += c;            //  add character (e.g. a)
        pstr.push_back(temp); // push the new string (e.g. Aa) to the vector 
    }

    const char* pstart{ "Your letter is " };

    int dice{};

    while (true)
    {
        cout << endl
            << "Enter a number between 1 and 26 " << pstr.size() << ": ";
        cin >> dice;
        if (dice == 0)
        {
            break; //break if the user enters 0
        }
        cout << endl;
        if (dice >= 1 && dice <= pstr.size())                            // Check input validity
            cout << pstart << pstr[dice - 1];                               // Output star name

        else
            cout << "Sorry, you haven't selected a correct number.";                    // Invalid input
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: O wow thank you.  I think I need to read more about vectors.  I appreciate every ones help

Comment: @Htog86 if you find any answer useful or comment, then upvote them. if there's an answer that answers your question, mark as answer. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong here:

```
while (keepgoing = true) {
  ...
  if (answer == 0) {
    keepgoing = false;
  }
}
```

You are setting the `keepgoing` to false, but in the `while` condition you are resenting it to `true`. You must use the `==` operator (as in `while(keepgoing == true)`) or remove it (`while(keepgoing)`).

Otherwise, you may use `while(true)` or `for (;;)` and break instead of `keepgoing = false`:

```
for (;;) { // or while (true); to me, that's only a matter of preference.
  ...
  if (answer == 0) {
    break; // exit the loop
  }
}
```

They do produce infinite loop until you enter the `break` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
while (keepgoing = true)
```

To this:

```
while (keepgoing == true)
```

The first assigns the value `true` to the variable `keepgoing`.  The second checks of the value of `keepgoing` is `true`.  This is a very common issue that trips of many new programmers (and occasionally an old one).  :-)